# How to get the last non empty value of a hierarchy?

Tags: sql, hierarchy, flatten

I've got a hierarchy with the appropriate value linked to each level, let's say :

```
A               100
  A1            NULL
  A2            NULL
B
  B1            NULL
  B2            1000
      B21       500 
      B22       500
  B3            NULL
```

This hierarchy is materialized in my database as a parent-child hierarchy

```
Hierarchy Table
------------------------
Id       Code      Parent_Id
1          A          NULL
2          A1          1
3          A2          3
4          B          NULL
5          B1          4
6          B2          4
7          B21         6
8          B22         6
9          B3          4
```

And here is my fact table :

```
Fact Table
------------------------
Hierarchy_Id          Value
1                      100
6                      1000
7                      500
8                      500
```

My question is : do you know/have any idea of how to get only the last non empty value of my hiearchy?
I know that there an MDX function which could do this job but I'd like to do this in an another way.

To be clear, the desired output would be :

```
Fact Table
------------------------
Hierarchy_Id          Value
1                      100
7                      500
8                      500
```

(If necessary, the work of flatten the hierarchy is already done...)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the codes for your hierarchy are correct, then you can use the information in the codes to determine the depth of the hierarchy.  I think you want to filter out any "code" where there is a longer code that starts with it.

In that case:

```
select f.*
from fact f join
     hierarchy h
     on f.hierarchyId = h.hierarchyId
where not exists (select 1
                  from fact f2 join
                       hierarchy h2
                       on f2.hierarchyId = h2.hierarchyId
                  where h2.code like concat(h.code, '%') and
                        h2.code <> h.code
                 )
```

Here I've used the function `concat()` to create the pattern.  In some databases, you might use `+` or `||` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't base my query on the code. But if you think that the depth of the hierarchy i can add a column in the hierarchy table.

Comment: @stormblow . . . That's a shame, because the question includes the code and it is quite useful.  Generating the code requires either iteration or recursive queries, which are highly database dependent.  The depth isn't sufficient, you need the entire hierarchy.